# Laravel missing make:auth command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I trying make login system in current laravel project with command `make:auth`. 
but somehow the `make:auth` command is missing from php artisan.

It weird because before I start my current project the command is available. So I tried update my composer anyway just to make sure. and it still missing in current project.

Tried make another new project and the `make:auth` command is available.

My question is, How to make the `make:auth` command available in current project without start all over in new project?

Comment: what version are you using? also, check your composr.json file make sure you have "laravel/framework" dependency

Comment: I checked composer json before update it. It said laravel installer 2.2. I change it to 5.8 and run composer update and, and it failed to update. It said the current intaller avaible [1.0.0...2.2.0] something like that. I also run php artisan in my current project it said laravel framework 5.9-dev, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: can you show your composer file

Comment: ah my bad `{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^2.2"
    }
}`

Comment: `laravel/installer` is a tool to download and setup Laravel framework, not the framework itself. your composer should have laravel/framework, something like this `"laravel/framework": "5.4.*"`

Comment: So what should do is add more another line in my composer.json file or just remove `laravel/installer`

Comment: Ok found json file and it's said `"laravel/framework": "5.9.*"`

Comment: **Laravel 5.9** is not yet released @Kribo26

Comment: I jsut check my composer json file in current project it said
`"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.9.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "4.3.1"`

Comment: I'm not sure but it said 5.9.*
I open this json file in my current project folder, is it json file I should looking for? or Json file in my composer folder. sorry if I confused because I new to this framework

Comment: Yup just change it to 5.8, and update it and it work. I don't know how I got laravel 5.9 in my json file. Thanks guys